# La variable del condicional no se encuentra disponible a todo el código Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, while

En este algoritmo no encuentro la forma de colocar a disponibilidad de todo el código la variable userNew pues debería almacenarla para utilizarla luego pero no es posible puesto que pertenece solo al scope del else if... a menos que la declare con var pero no debería. Me pregunto entonces si está mal definida la lógica del ciclo while y del condicional if o como debería poder almacenar y utilizar luego esa variable userNew...

```
// Definir la funcion
function USER(nombre, clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}

// Definir constantes
const USER1 = new USER ('Pedro', 5905);
const USER2 = new USER ('Jose', 1134);
const USER3 = new USER ('Ana', 3517);
const USER4 = new USER ('Juan', 4731);

// Variable de entrada
let userIn = prompt('Si Ud. esta registrado, ingrese su nombre, de lo contrario, ingrese 1');

// Validaciones de los datos ingresados
while (userIn == '') {
    userIn = prompt("Ingrese un nombre por favor!");
}
if (userIn == (USER1.nombre) || (USER2.nombre) || (USER3.nombre) || (USER4.nombre)) {
    let passIn = Number( prompt('Ingrese su clave numerica de 4 digitos'));
    if(passIn === (USER1.clave) || (USER2.clave) || (USER3.clave) || (USER4.clave)) {
        alert('Bienvenido a su hogar ' + userIn);
    }

} else if (userIn == 1){
    let userNew = Number( prompt('Para generar un usuario nuevo, ingrese clave maestro'));
} else {
    alert('Ud. no es un usuario registrado, favor de retirarse');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como expongo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488756/la-variable-del-condicional-no-se-encuentra-disponible-a-todo-el-c%c3%b3digo-javascri/488758?noredirect=1#comment868922_488758), la idea es realizar la declaración de la variable (usando `let`) en el ámbito superior (*top-most outer scope*) de tu aplicación o script. Esto garantiza que la misma sea accesible desde cualquier punto dentro de dicho *ámbito*.

Por otro lado, tienes un error en la lógica de la comparación:

```js
if (userIn == (USER1.nombre) || (USER2.nombre) || (USER3.nombre) || (USER4.nombre))
```

Lo que está del lado derecho del operador de comparación (`==`) devolverá `true` o `false` dependiendo del resultado de la siguiente lógica:

```js
(USER1.nombre) || (USER2.nombre) || (USER3.nombre) || (USER4.nombre)
```

Dado que los valores de la propiedad `nombre` de cada objeto `USER` es una cadena no vacía, el resultado de todo esto es `true`.

Esta no es la forma de comparar si una cadena coincide con alguno de los valores almacenados en tus variables.

Una forma es la que sugiere la [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488756/la-variable-del-condicional-no-se-encuentra-disponible-a-todo-el-c%c3%b3digo-javascri/488758#488758):

```js
if ((userIn == USER1.nombre) || (userIn == USER2.nombre) || (userIn == USER3.nombre) || (userIn == USER4.nombre))
```

Pero esto se vuelve cada vez más engorroso si tenemos muchos más objetos por analizar.

Otra forma de hacerlo es definir un `Array` de objetos e iterar sus elementos, y otra forma es usar directamente los métodos propios de un `Array` para hacer todo un poco más compacto.

Sin alterar mucho la estructura de tu código vamos a plantearlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Definir la funcion
function USER(nombre, clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}

// Definir constantes
const USER1 = new USER ('Pedro', 5905);
const USER2 = new USER ('Jose', 1134);
const USER3 = new USER ('Ana', 3517);
const USER4 = new USER ('Juan', 4731);

// Definir lista de usuarios
const users = [
  USER1,
  USER2,
  USER3,
  USER4,
];

// Variable de entrada
let userIn = prompt('Si Ud. esta registrado, ingrese su nombre, de lo contrario, ingrese 1');

if(users.map(user => user.nombre).includes(userIn)) {
  alert('Nombre encontrado: ' + userIn);
} else {
  alert('Lo siento, no existe: ' + userIn);
}
```

Hemos construido un `Array` de usuarios, luego, usamos el método [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para obtener dinámicamente un `Array` con los nombres de cada usuario. Luego a dicho `Array` le aplicamos el método [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) que devuelve verdadero o falso según el parámetro pasado se encuentre en la lista o no.
De esta forma, estamos cambiando esta sentencia:

```js
if ((userIn == USER1.nombre) || (userIn == USER2.nombre) || (userIn == USER3.nombre) || (userIn == USER4.nombre))
```

por esta otra:

```js
if(users.map(user => user.nombre).includes(userIn))
```

La cual es más compacta, aunque estoy de acuerdo en que no es trivial al principio.

Una vez que hemos resuelto el primer problema veamos cómo resolver el segundo: la asignación de `newUser`. Tal como lo tienes actualmente, la variable `newUser` almacena el valor del `prompt`, y no almacena realmente un nuevo usuario:

```js
newUser = Number(prompt(...));
```

Si no entiendo mal el propósito de tu programa, deseas guardar un nuevo usuario a partir de los datos introducidos, pero no estás logrando dicho propósito al no crear una nueva instancia del objeto `USER`.

Lo que sugiero que debes hacer es crear el nuevo usuario preguntando sus datos y almacenando los mismos en un nuevo objeto `USER` de la siguiente forma:

```js
// Definir la funcion
function USER(nombre, clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}

let newUser;

let userIn = prompt('Si Ud. esta registrado, ingrese su nombre, de lo contrario, ingrese 1');

if(userIn === '1') {
  let nombre = prompt('Ingrese el nombre:');
  let clave = prompt('Ingrese clave');
  newUser = new USER(nombre,clave);
}

console.log(newUser);
```

Luego, podríamos añadir el nuevo usuario a la lista de usuarios existentes, lo cual nos permite una forma muy básica de persistir la información recién creada. Para añadir el nuevo usuario a la lista podemos hacer uso del método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

El código completo (muy básico) podría verse así:

```js
/**
* Ámbito global a mi programa o script
* Todo lo que declare en este ámbito estará disponible
* para cualquier función o mñetodo que lo necesite
**/

// Definir la funcion (alcance global en este ámbito)
function USER(nombre, clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}

// Definir constantes
const USER1 = new USER ('Pedro', 5905);
const USER2 = new USER ('Jose', 1134);
const USER3 = new USER ('Ana', 3517);
const USER4 = new USER ('Juan', 4731);

// Definir variable global en este ámbito
let userNew;  // <- nótese que no se le asigna valor

// Lista de usuarios
const users = [
      USER1,
      USER2,
      USER3,
      USER4,
    ];

// Variable de entrada
let userIn = prompt('Si Ud. esta registrado, ingrese su nombre, de lo contrario, ingrese 1');

// Validaciones de los datos ingresados
while (userIn === '') {
    userIn = prompt("Ingrese un nombre por favor!");
}
if (users.map(user => user.nombre).includes(userIn)) {
    let passIn = Number( prompt('Ingrese su clave numerica de 4 digitos'));
    if(users.map(user => user.clave).includes(passIn)) {
        alert('Bienvenido a su hogar ' + userIn);
    }
    else {
        alert('Clave inválida');
    }

} else if (userIn === '1'){
    let nombre = prompt('Ingrese su nombre:');
    let clave = prompt('Ingrese su clave:');
    userNew = new USER(nombre, clave);
    //añadimos el nuevo usuario a la lista
    users.push(userNew);
} else {
    alert('Ud. no es un usuario registrado, favor de retirarse');
}

console.log(userNew);
console.log(users);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora bien, esto parece que sería una buena práctica hasta que tu aplicación comienza a crecer y te das cuenta que llenar el ámbito global con variables no es tan elegante. Existen formas de mitigar este problema, pero está fuera del alcance de la pregunta.

Por otro lado, cuando dices esto:

```
// Definir constantes
const USER1 = new USER ('Pedro', 5905);
```

has de tener en cuenta que si bien has definido las variables como constantes, aún podrás alterar sus propiedades, es decir, tan *constantes* no son. Realmente lo que sucede es que no podrás *reasignar* el valor de una constante, pero en el caso de los objetos (incluyendo `Array`, `Function`, `Object`, etc.) las propiedades y elementos del mismo si que pueden ser alterados. Puedes darte cuenta que la lista de usuarios es declarada con `const` sin embargo he podido añadir un elemento a la misma sin problemas.

Todo esto viene de un concepto muy primitivo llamado *puntero*. Y es que una variable realmente es un *puntero* hacia una dirección de memoria, es decir una referencia a una posición en memoria, y esta referencia es de sólo lectura, es decir no puedes cambiar el valor de esta referencia, pero si puedes alterar el contenido del objeto que está almacenado en dicha posición de memoria, siempre y cuando el mismo sea *mutable*.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal consturídos los condicionales if, tienes que poner todas las comparaciones. Para que userNew sea visible fuera de su bloque tendrás que declararla como var.

```
function USER(nombre, clave) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.clave = clave;
}

// Definir constantes
const USER1 = new USER ('Pedro', 5905);
const USER2 = new USER ('Jose', 1134);
const USER3 = new USER ('Ana', 3517);
const USER4 = new USER ('Juan', 4731);

// Variable de entrada
let userIn = prompt('Si Ud. esta registrado, ingrese su nombre, de lo contrario, ingrese 1');

// Validaciones de los datos ingresados
while (userIn == '') {
    userIn = prompt("Ingrese un nombre por favor!");
}
if ((userIn == USER1.nombre) || (userIn == USER2.nombre) || (userIn == USER3.nombre) || (userIn == USER4.nombre)) {
    let passIn = Number( prompt('Ingrese su clave numerica de 4 digitos'));
    if((passIn === USER1.clave) || (passIn === USER2.clave) || (passIn === USER3.clave) || (passIn === USER4.clave)) {
        alert('Bienvenido a su hogar ' + userIn);
    }

} else if (userIn == 1){
    var userNew = Number( prompt('Para generar un usuario nuevo, ingrese clave maestro'));
} else {
    alert('Ud. no es un usuario registrado, favor de retirarse');
}
console.log(userNew)
```

Verás que ahora userNew si aparece accesible.

Comment: O declarar `userNew` como variable global con `let` y usarla luego directamente dentro del condicional.

Comment: let no declara la variable como global, todo lo contrario es super local dentro del bloque donde se declare.

Comment: Entiendo que la declaración con `let` tiene alcance de bloque, pero si declaras en el bloque más externo, será global dentro de dicho contexto. A lo que me refiero es a que puede declararla al nivel más externo sin definir su valor y luego usarla en cualquier otro ámbito dentro del mismo alcance en que fue declarada. No digo que tu aproximación esté mal, sólo que a **mi** (preferencia muy personal) no me gusta mezclar `var` con `let y `const`, eso es todo. ;)

Comment: Exacto @MauricioContreras, pero justamente eso es lo que no encuentro como hacer... es decir, no hallo como definir en código eso que decís...